# MySQL, json data type, returning limited number of results

Tags: mysql, json

Lets say I have a json field that looks like this

```
{
   "unknownkey":{..},
   "unknownkey":{..},
   "unknownkey":{..},
}
```

For specific users, I can CRUD with this field easily, without resorting to mysql's json search functionality, because the unknown key includes the user id (and thus becomes known). I can target it by path.

Where I'm running into issues is getting generic results out of it.

1) How would I grab just the first result out of it, when the key is not known?

2) How do I limit the number of results? Say, I only want 25 results, not the whole json document (which could potentially be massive).

3) What if I want the NEXT 25 results (aka 25-50).

For (1), I've tried setting a mysql variable to something like

```
@test = JSON_KEYS(fieldname, '$')[0]
```

then plugging that into my reference

```
fieldname->'$.[@test]'
```

Something like that, with different variations, can't get that to work. I don't love this type of option either, it seems like there should be a much easier way.

For (2) and (3), I've scoured https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html and can't seem to find it anywhere.

Any help/thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: When using build in functions on json, it will do a parse of the document, thus processing all values. To limit to just 25 values in real parsing, you would have to create your own parser (I build one when this whole json parser in mysql was unstable: 20 lines of code should do it)

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, MySQL 8 has the solution to this (has really good support for an unknown number of array of objects), so check out the MySQL 8 docs. I believe the most recent milestone release has it on there, but the release is too early to be considered stable yet.